# How do I targeting selector with addTarget in another class

Tags: swift, events, target

I try to understand how to control component form one class to another class but that's not working.

```
class VC:UIViewController {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        let instance = Test()
        self.view.addSubView(instance.button)
    }
}

class Test:NSObject {
    var button:UIButton!

    override init() {
        button = UIButton(frame:CGRect(x:0, y:0, width:100, height:40))
        button.setTitle(("TEST", for:.normal)
        button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(tapButton(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)
    }

    @objc func tapButton(_ sender:UIButton) {
        print("TAP Button")
    }
}
```

When I tapped the button, nothing happens !
I try to change

```
button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(tapButton(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)
```

with

```
button.addTarget(nil, action: #selector(tapButton(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)
```

That's not working !

How to resolve this problem ?
Thanks for your help.

Comment: You cannot redirect to a _class_, you need an instance (like `self`) to redirect the action to.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have 3 issues:

1. `instance` is a local variable, so it gets deallocated as soon as `viewDidLoad()` finishes.  Make it a property of `VC`.  The button only keeps a weak reference to the object, so when it is deallocated it becomes `nil`.  In cases where the target is `nil`, UIKit will search up the responder chain for the action method.  Since `VC` doesn't supply a `tapButton` method, nothing happens when the button is pressed.
2. You need to call `super.init()` so that `self` is available to be used with the button.  `self` can't be created until all properties have been initialized.  Because `init` is an `override`, you must call `super.init()` to initialize the properties that `NSObject` provides before you can use `self` in the button.
3. Your frame puts your button in an unaccessible region of the screen.  I changed your frame to put the button inside the safe area of the iPhone 11.  I also made the button `.green` so that I could see it.

```
class VC: UIViewController {
    var instance = Test()          // make instance a property
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        // let instance = Test()   // this was a local variable that doesn't hang around
        self.view.addSubview(instance.button)
    }


}


class Test: NSObject {
    var button: UIButton!

    override init() {
        super.init()  // call this so that you can use self below
        button = UIButton(frame:CGRect(x: 100, y: 100, width: 100, height: 40))
        button.setTitle("TEST", for:.normal)
        button.backgroundColor = .green
        button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(tapButton(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)
    }

    @objc func tapButton(_ sender: UIButton) {
        print("TAP Button")
    }

    // Add deinit to see when this object is deinitialized.  When
    // instance is local to viewDidLoad() this object gets freed
    // when viewDidLoad() finishes.
    deinit {
        print("Oops, the Test object has been deinitialized")
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks for your answer could you explain purpose of the using call super init and capable of using the self, I think it is one tricky part

Comment: The interesting thing is that everything wrong with the project is in getting it set up so that you could see a button and tap it. The button was both not visible, so you couldn't tap it. What I would have expected was for the app to crash when you tapped the button, since, as you pointed out, the Test object gets deallocated immediately, so the target no longer exists by the time you could tap the button.

Comment: Thanks @vacawama, it's works perfectly. I miss the first issue.

Comment: @DuncanC, the button only has a weak reference to the object, and when the object is deallocated it becomes `nil`.  If the target is `nil`, iOS searches up the responder chain for the action method.  A funny thing to try is to add a second `tapButton` function to `VC` and then it will be called if `instance` is a local variable, but the one in `instance` will be called when `instance` is stored as a property.

Comment: @sekoyaz, I updated the answer to give more info on `super.init()`.

Comment: @vacawama at the time the OP's code calls `addTarget(_:,action:for:)`, target is not nil. I haven't looked at the internals of UIControl and how it manages target/actions. You're saying that it holds a weak reference to the target, which becomes nil when the target gets deallocated? I sort of expected the target to be owned by a dictionary or some other strong reference. (The target/action mechanism long predates auto-nilling weak references, after all.)

Comment: The big take-away for the OP is that as their code was written, the `Test` object was created in a local variable inside a function, and nobody kept a strong reference to it. When you do that, and object gets deallocated as soon as you leave the function (or shortly thereafter.) If you want an object to stick around, you need to keep a strong reference to it.

Comment: @DuncanC, in a project I printed `button.allTargets` in `viewDidLoad()` and got `[AnyHashable(<TestProject.Test: 0x6000034e4130>)]` then later after the object was freed and `button.allTargets` was `[AnyHashable(<null>)]`.

Comment: @vacawama thanks. this question is kind of interview question contains core concepts and asking find the 3 main mistakes. btw congrats you got the job ! ˆ - ˆ

Comment: @sekoyaz, LOL, great!